# C++ order of execution of functions that return string

Tags: java, c++

I have this two functions and a variable in a class:

```
int _identation = 0;

std::string ident(){
    _identation++;
    return "";
}

std::string newLine(){
    std::string text = "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < _identation; i++){
        text+="\t";
    }
    return text;
}
```

The **ident()** function just increments a variable and returns **std::string** (just to allow me to use it inline with strings).

The function **newLine()** creates a new line with the char '\n' and places _identation '\t' to make the next line incremented.

I don´t now if it is relevant to the question but i am using some kind of **visitor design pattern**. I tried to do this on my code:

```
std::string content = "<page>"+ident()+newLine();
```

but it happens that my compiler makes the newLine() function run first and only after it calls the ident() function. So if I want to ident my code before creating a new line I have to use this expression:

```
std::string content = "<page>"+newLine()+ident();
```

Why does C++ read this line from the right side to the left? I also made this exact program in Java and JVM executes this expression from the left to the right.

Thanks :)

Comment: The order of evaluation of functions in C++ is unspecified. If the functions you are calling in an indeterminately sequenced expression has ordering requirements, your program will surely be buggy

Comment: @WhiZTiM thanks for your reply. What would you recommend in my situation? Use parenthesis or dividi this expression in multiple line?

Comment: Multiple statements.  I don't think parentheses are going to help.  If you need things to be executed in a specified order, write multiple statements that execute in a specified order.  It's that simple.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the clarification. Just to make sure in Java this expression is evaluated from left to right, right? I want to make sure that my java version of this won´t get buggy.

Comment: Right, the Java rules make it clear that it's from left to right.  That doesn't mean you should write it that way.  I still think it's better to write separate statements.  If you write one expression, it won't be clear to a reader that your expression is dependent on the order of execution.

Comment: Also, please note that `indent` has an `n` after the "i".  The main reason this is important is that `ident` is a fairly common abbreviation for "identification".

Comment: In fact, it looks like you're trying to write a "trick" so that you can compress indentation and output commands into one line.  Please avoid using tricks.  They make things harder to understand, and are more prone to bugs especially when someone else goes back and tries to modify your code.  The benefits you get from being able to shove everything into one line usually isn't worth it.  You should have a **void** method named `increase_indentation` or something.

Comment: @ajb you are right indeed. To avoid more errors I will make the function indent() return void. And I will stop using it inline.

Comment: You could just pass the indentation level to `newline` as a parameter, `newline(_identation())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing them in different lines.

```
std::string content = "<page>";
content+ident();
content+newLine();
```